# Problem with QGIS GDAL Fill Nodata

Tags: qgis, gdal, landsat-7, gap

I have been using the 'GDAL Fill Nodata' function in QGIS in order to rectify downloaded Landsat 7 images, having created a relevant mask. Whilst said function has been successful in resolving bands 1 - 7 and satellite zenith, solar azimuth and solar zenith images, errors occur in regards to the satellite azimuth data. I have run the exact same function on each band [image].

The below represents the original satellite azimuth image (with gaps on both sides

[[image: The below represents the original satellite azimuth image (with gaps on both sides)[1]]

[image: The second picture is the (corrected) image output by the GDAL Fill Nodata function. As can be seen, the image has not been corrected as anticipated]

[image: Image 3 shows the original satellite zenith with gaps]

[image: Image 4 shows the corrected image output by QGIS.]

The second picture is the (corrected) image output by the GDAL Fill Nodata function. As can be seen, the image has not been corrected as anticipated

Image 3 shows the original satellite zenith with gaps

Image 4 shows the corrected image output by QGIS

Does anyone have any ideas why the function would work on every other image, but not the satellite azimuth image?